# how can I name my different pins while I keep having them all?

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, maps

When I do it like this:

```
                var ourPin = new Pin {

                    //info

                };

                ourPin.Clicked += (sender, args) => {
                //pushasync
                };

                map.Pins.Add (ourPin);
```

It works but if I try to add another pin to my map in add (), i can only enter 1 pin. So i did it like this instead but I dont know how I should be able to name each one of the pins:

```
            map.Pins.Add (new Pin {

            //info

            });
            map.Pins.Add(new Pin {

            //info

            });

            //how can i pushasync each pin?
```

with this method i get both of the pins but as I mentioned above, how can I name each one of them so I can make a Clickfunction with each pin?

Comment: What is driving the creation of a pin? Like, is there a list of Location-ish instances that have a Latitude, Longitude, and Name? You could iterate over the input list, create the pin, assign the Click handler, and add it to Map.Pins just as you did in the first example, only in a loop.

Comment: yeah i have that all figured out, but i want to make every pin unique so i can click them and get different info inside them. if i use the first code above the code itself works but i cannot add more than 1 pin so the code on the second paragraph gives me the pins atleast but i dont know how to name them so i can create a .clicked function with it

Comment: You could add your input instances T to a Dictionary<Pin,  T>, then use sender as Pin to get the input instance from the dictionary on click. Presumably the T instance would have the additional data you want.

Comment: hmm ok. how would that look? not quite sure how i would implement that (im kinda new)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, tapping this on phone. If no one chimes in sooner, I'll post some code tomorrow from a real keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var pin = new Pin();
pin.Label = "Pin A";
pin.Address = "blah";
pin.Position = new Position(x1,y1);
pin.Clicked += Pin_Clicked;

map.Pins.Add(pin);

pin = new Pin();
pin.Label = "Pin B";
pin.Address = "blah";
pin.Position = new Position(x2,y2);
pin.Clicked += Pin_Clicked;

map.Pins.Add(pin);

pin = new Pin();
pin.Label = "Pin C";
pin.Address = "blah";
pin.Position = new Position(x3,y3);
pin.Clicked += Pin_Clicked;

map.Pins.Add(pin);

void Pin_Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Pin pin = (Pin)sender;

    // now pin is the Pin that was clicked, look at it's properties
    // to determine which pin and act accordingly
}
```

Comment: i create a Pin_Clicked1, Pin_Clicked2 now etc etc but I have like 10 pins, is there an easier way?

Comment: You only need one event handler, that's why I only have one in my example.  Every pin uses the same handler, and the sender argument tells the handler which Pin has been clicked.

Comment: oh ok and how can I make the info on the pushed page change information depending on what the user clicked? for example I have a string on the page the clicked on a pin goes to

Comment: now I have the code: Navigation.PushAsync (new DetailPage ("Pin")); and every page gets "Pin" as a label on the next page, how can I make it so you only get that message to a certain pin?

Comment: just pass pin.Label, or the entire pin object

Comment: cant find variable "pin" in my new void function

Comment: I don't know what YOUR code looks like.   Look at MY example.  I have a "pin" variable in my Pin_Clicked handler that represents the specific pin that was clicked.

Comment: Pin pin = (Pin)sender;

Navigation.PushAsync (new DetailPage ("test")); and on my detailpag the code just looks like this: public DetailPage (string info1) {
   InitializeComponent ();

   infothe1.Text = info1;
  }

Comment: It gives me "test" now on every pin I clicked, I want to create the info in the new page unique somehow. so depending on the pin u clicked u get this info and if u click that pin u get another info.

Comment: That is because you are passing the hardcoded value "test" every time!  Use the unique value you get from the pin object instead.

Comment: Navigation.PushAsync (new DetailPage ((Pin) sender)); ??

Comment: sure, if your DetailPage can accept a Pin object.  Or if it only accepts a string, pass the Pin's Label property.

Comment: Thx alot Jason. Works now!